# Getting all items without open end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to solve following problem using (My)SQL, given is this example table:

```
id | item | start      | end
1  | 100  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-14
2  | 100  | 2015-01-01 | NULL
3  | 101  | 2015-03-01 | 2015-04-15
4  | 101  | 2015-04-17 | 2015-04-22
5  | 101  | 2015-04-27 | 2015-05-11
```

I need a query that gives me all items where there is no open end date. So from the above I'd expect to get 101.

I tried it with GROUP and some sub-selects but didn't show up like I expected. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select item
from example
group by item
having count(end) = count(*);
```

`count()` with a column names counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  If this is equal to the number of rows, then no values are `NULL`.

You could also use:

```
having sum(end is null) = 0
```

EDIT:

I should add that the following might be faster, assuming you have the right indexes and a table for items:

```
select i.item
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from example e
                  where i.item = e.item and e.end is null
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `example(item, end)`.